# generating dynamic html, name value changes using javascript. error:- Unexpected string or identifier

Tags: javascript

Here I am trying to generate dynamic html with unique name on the basis of iteration. But error "unexpected identifier and unexpected string" is coming. I tried following :-

```
 for (i = 0; i < num_units; i++) {
  units_html += '<tr><td><input type="'text'" name="'unit_name'+ i + '"</td></tr>';                       
        }
 for (i = 0; i < num_units; i++) {
 units_html += "<tr><td><input type='text' name='unit_name'" + i + "></td></tr>";                      
        }
```

I know, I am doing any stupid mistake, but now unable to identify it.. any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at the colors of the code above, and notice that you're missing the `+` sign between variables and text etc. and have mismatched quotes.

Comment: @adeneo: are you talking about type='text' ? Do I use + here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some typos, here is corrected. Also don't forget to initialize units_html if you didn't do it:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_units; i++) {
  units_html += '<tr><td><input type="text" name="unit_name'+ i + '"</td></tr>';                       
        }
 for (i = 0; i < num_units; i++) {
 units_html += "<tr><td><input type='text' name='unit_name'" + i + "></td></tr>";                      
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for right answer and yes I have initialize before writing it. :)

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the concatenation operator:

```
'<tr><td><input type="text" name="' + unit_name + i + '"</td></tr>'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (i = 0; i < num_units; i++) {
  units_html += '<tr><td><input type="text" name="'unit_name + i'"></td></tr>';                       
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just fixed some quotes, this might be what you are looking for:

```
for (i = 0; i < num_units; i++) {
  units_html += 
 '<tr><td><input type="'text'" name="'unit_name+ i + '"</td></tr>';                       
    }
 for (i = 0; i < num_units; i++) {
units_html += "<tr><td><input type='text' name='"unit_name + i + "'></td></tr>";                      
       }
```